Exponential law for topological spaces
Theorem: Given three topological spaces $X,Y,Z$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff and $Y$ is locally compact then the natural map
$$\hom(X\times Y,Z)\rightarrow\hom(X,\hom(Y,Z))$$
induces homomorphism. Where the hom spaces are gives compact-open topology.
I was reading the paper “A primer on Homotopy Colimit” by Daniel dugger where he keeps using the following fact which I have mentioned as a question.
Question: If all the above spaces are Hausdorff and $X=\Delta^n$, where $\Delta^n$ is topological $n$-simplex and no assumption on $Y$ being locally compact. Does the same Exponential law hold?

Where precisely does the author use this?

On page 36 remark 9.6, where one has to go from tot of cosimplicial to realization(hocolim)

Another one, proposition 9.9 on the same page.

I do not think that hom-spaces are given the compact-open topology.
On p.24 the author writes

When generalizing to homotopy limits and colimits, the difference is that one replaces the set of maps in $\mathscr{T}\mathcal{op}$ with the mapping space $\operatorname{Map}(X, Y)$ (also denoted $X^Y$). For this we need to assume we are working in a 'good' category of spaces where the mapping space is a true right adjoint (like the category of compactly generated
spaces).

This means that products and function spaces are re-topologized by applying the $k$-functor which associates to each Hausdorff space $X$ a compactly generated Hausdorff space $k(X)$ which in general has a finer topology than $X$. For a compactly generated $X$ one has $k(X) = X$. The usual product $X \times Y$ of compactly generated spaces is in general not a compactly generated, thus one replaces it by $k(X \times Y)$ which gives a product in the category of compactly generated spaces. Similarly one understands $\operatorname{Map}(X, Y)$ as $k(X^Y)$, where $X^Y$ has the compact open topology.
See for example Theorem 6.5 in

Davis, James F., and Paul Kirk. Lecture notes in algebraic topology. Vol. 35. Providence: American Mathematical Society, 2001.


So in general what I have asked is not true. I went through the notes you mentioned where the adjunction is proved with spaces replaced by the compactly generated version of it.

@MukilrajK I do not have an example where it fails. But I am fairly sure that such examples exists.
